# Calculated field in ACCESS IIF

Tags: ms-access-2016, calculated-field

In access I have a column, called ID number and a column called Short ID. The problem is that the ID number has changed over time- it used to contain letters, numbers, and dashes and now it only contains numbers.

For the new IDs the formula: Right([ID number],6) gives me what I need (the last 6 characters)

but for the old IDs id only like the last 4 characters Right([ID number],4)

Is there a formula I could write so that anytime the ID number contains a dash "-" it gives the the last 4 characters and anytime it doesn't it gives me the last 6?

Answer (score 0):

This fancy expression will do that:

```
TextNumber = StrReverse(Mid(Val("1" & StrReverse([ID number])), 2))
```

The `"1"` is to preserve leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work for me!
Thanks for your help.

```
IIf(ID number] Like "*-*",Right([ID number],4),Right([ID number],6))
```